# Stumping in cricket

Tags: cricket, icc, cricket-world-cup

[image]

[image][image]

The batsman missed the ball and even the keeper couldn't catch it. The ball was in the air after touching the keeper's hand, the batsman was inside of the crease. Later the keeper took the ball and was trying to give it back to the bowler and at the same time the batsman came out of the crease while balancing himself,  and the keeper stumped him.
The batsman's intention was not to take  a run but was trying to balance himself.

Is that out or not out?

[image][image]

Comment: Could you confirm exactly which match this is from?

Comment: @PhilipKendall - after a bit of a google... it's Sussex Sharks (blue) vs Hampshire (yellow) in the T20 Blast (24 July 2019) - Also found [highlights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMUYj2Ohe2Q) - stumping at 0:54

Answer (score 2):

I initially wrote this as a comment on [Nij's Answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/22845/6216) but thought it deserved its own answer.

**It depends on if the Umpire has deemed the ball to be dead**

From [Law 20 - Dead Ball](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/dead-ball)

> **20.1.1** The ball becomes dead when
>
> **20.1.1.1** it is finally settled in the hands of the wicket-keeper or of the bowler.
>
> [...]
>
> **20.1.2** The ball shall be considered to be dead when it is clear to the bowler’s end umpire that the fielding side and both batsmen at the wicket have ceased to regard it as in play.

And

> **20.2** Ball finally settled
>
> Whether the ball is finally settled or not is a matter for the umpire alone to decide.

So in this case, does the umpire deem the wicketkeeper's action to start throwing back the ball to the bowler as ***finally settled in the hands of the wicket-keeper***, or ***the fielding side and both batsmen at the wicket have ceased to regard it as in play***?

If the umpire still believes the ball to still be in play, then it is **Out** as highlighted in Nij's answer.

---

**Edit**

In actual fact the batsman (LJ Evans) in this case was out **Run Out**, not stumped, as the umpire has deemed the batsman to be attempting a run (probably because he thought the wicket-keeper has missed the ball), and not trying to regain their balance.

[Scorecard](https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8053/scorecard/1167145/sussex-vs-hampshire-south-group-vitality-blast)

Answer (score 1):

The batsman is clearly **Out, Stumped**. The situation meets all four requirements of Law 39.1.1:

1. The ball is delivered and not a No ball,
2. the batsman is out of their ground,
3. the batsman has not attempted a run, and
4. the wicket is put down by the wicketkeeper without intervention by another fielder.

Since the exception in Law 39.3.1 does not apply (the batsman is trying to keep balanced, not avoid injury) they are Out Stumped.

Comment: I think the only possible saviour for the batsman here, would be if the umpire has deemed the play to be dead - either by the act of throwing the ball back to the bowler (or other fielder), or through length of time the wicketkeeper has had the ball; in which case it would be Not Out. Though it's quite hard to tell with stills, and not a video :/